# UIImagePickerController not compressing a video

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a `UIImagePickerController` and I want the users to be able to pick videos and photos for their photos. There's no problem allowing that, but when I select a video (I'm testing this on a iPhone XR simulator) it shows the compressing video screen and it never process the video. And it's not a long video, it's just a sample demo video (5 seconds long). The video plays normally in the simulator, but for some reason it's stuck on the compression.

It's not just this video, its ANY video and I'm not sure if im doing something wrong or not.

```
@objc func handleSelectPhoto() {
    let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    pickerController.delegate = self
    pickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.image", "public.movie"]
    present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
extension PostVC : UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let videoUrl = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL {
        self.videoUrl = videoUrl
        print(videoUrl)
    }
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImage = image
        photoImageView.image = image
        shareButton.isEnabled = true
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

All I see is this:

[image]

Oh and once I select "Choose", you cannot hit anything else. The UI is stuck completely.

Comment: The same issue with real devices sometimes once you click choose it compresses the video and now you can not hit any button cancel and choosing both not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the issue is within the simulator. I ran the app on my iPhone and it chooses and compresses the video without any problem.